# useQuasar() returns undefined in pinia store file - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar, pinia

In my VueJS + Quasar project, I am trying to use `useQuasar()` in my store `gallery.js` file. But it returns undefined.

I had the same problem when accessing `useRouter()`, but then I found a solution. We have a `router` export in `node_modules/quasar/wrappers/index` file, so I used that to pass in my stores from main store index.js file:

```
import { route, store } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import { markRaw } from 'vue';

export default store((/* { ssrContext } */) => {
  const pinia = createPinia();

  pinia.use(({ store }) => {
    store.router = markRaw(route);
  });

  return pinia;
})
```

My sample store file:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { useQuasar } from "quasar";
export const useGalleryStore = defineStore('gallery', {
    actions: {
        test_function() {
            const $q = useQuasar();
            console.log($q); // undefined
        }
    }
})
```

I tried to find `quasar` export also in `node_modules/quasar/wrappers/index` file but there is no `quasar` export in that file, so I don't see any way to use `this.$q` or `$q` or `useQuasar()` in my store file.

My usages are that I need `$q.notify()`, `$q.platform`, and `$q.screen`.

Is there any way to use them inside store file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quasar doesn't allow the use `this.$q` or `useQuasar` outside of .vue components.

If you want to use outside component, you should use:

```
import { Quasar, Platform } from 'quasar'

console.log(Quasar.version)
console.log(Platform.is.ios)
```

Source: https://quasar.dev/options/the-q-object#outside-of-a-vue-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use as this:

```
import { Notify } from 'quasar'

Notify.create('Danger, Will Robinson! Danger!')
// or with a config object:
Notify.create({
  message: 'Danger, Will Robinson! Danger!'
})
```

Source: https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/notify/

Be sure to enable Notify plugin first.